# EclipseRCP get pluginId in which a class is located

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an objects of class T that belongs to plugin P.
It is possible to retrieve the Plugin ID, trough class T?

I don't have access to plugin object but I have access to a objects that is an inner class of plugin P, I have access to PluginClassDescriptor. I have access to:

```
P.T object; // I need P.pluginID
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want the plug-in id? This isn't usually particularly useful.

Comment: I need to get some images from the plugin. But dropped this idea, over the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Bundle` for any plug-in class using:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(anyobject.getClass());
```

where `anyobject' is an instance of some class belonging to the plug-in.

The plug-in id is known as the 'symbolic name' in the bundle:

```
String pluginid = bundle.getSymbolicName();
```

`FrameworkUtil` is `org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil` in the `org.eclipse.osgi` plug-in.